# Assign Array to Variable without Extra Blank Line in Perl

Tags: arrays, perl, variables, loops, foreach

I'm writing a perl script that uploads the contents from an array into a database. To do this, I've created a "foreach" statement that loops through the array and assigns its contents into a variable:

```
foreach my $line (@array)
    { $data .= "$line\n" }
```

This script works, and I'm able to upload the variable into my database. However, thanks to the new line character at the end of my statement (used to retain the original line breaks of my array), my variable contains an extra blank line at the end, that also get's put into the database. 
What is the best way to get rid of this blank line? Is this something that I can only really fix after the loop? I'm extremely new to Perl, so I'm a bit confused. Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
my $data = join "\n", @array;
```

The `join` builtin takes a separator and a list, and concatenates the elements of your list. It is equivalent to

```
sub join ($@) {
  my $sep = shift;
  @_ or return "";
  my $str = shift;
  $str .= $sep . shift while @_;
  return $str;
}
```

Comment: ;) 35 seconds faster, and  wrote 3x more... i'm a slow typer :(

Answer (score 4):

Maybe you can try the next:

```
my $data = join "\n", @array;
```